# How to solve the situation that all values are 0 after dimensionality reduction using pytorch.argmax？

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network, argmax

As shown in the following code, after I put the input image into the model to obtain the output, I want to use argmax to reduce the dimensionality, but the results after argmax all become 0. What is the reason for this, should I use other methods for dimensionality reduction? Or change my model?

```
newModel = CNNSEG()
newModel.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
newModel.eval()

for iteration, sample in enumerate(test_data_loader):
    img = sample

    # output the results
    inputs = img.unsqueeze(1)
    outputs = newModel(inputs) # shape: [2, 4, 96, 96]
    print('outputs',outputs)
    # argmax
    #print(outputs.shape)
    out = torch.argmax(outputs, dim=1) # shape: [2,96,96]
    print('out',out)
```

The result of out is shown below, but all have values in outputs.

```
tensor([[[0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
         ...,
         [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0]],

        [[0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
         ...,
         [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0]]])
```

Comment: It means that in the first dimension, the values at the zeroth index always have the highest value, across the entire tensor. Why this happens depends on your data, problem, etc.

Comment: This may be a problem of my model selection. After I switch to another model, it can work normally. Anyway, thank you so much.